# How to get which data point was in which cluster based on flexmix

Tags: r

I have done cluster analysis using flexmix.

```
m7 <- stepFlexmix(ADA ~ NLEAD + BIG4 + LOGMKT + LEV + ROA + ROAL + LOSS +  
                       CFO + BTM + GROWTH + ALTMAN + ABSACCRL + 
                       STDEARN + TENURE + LOGASSETS, data = dt,
                  control = list(verbose = 0), k = 1:5, nrep = 5)

m7 <- getModel(m7, "BIC");
```

However, I am not sure how to extract the info that which data point fell in which cluster. Someone suggest the solution. Thanks.

Comment: `modeltools::clusters(getModel(m7, "BIC"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the function `str()` you can see the structure of the object `m7` (object made with function `stepFlexmix()` and not the `getModel()`) and you will see that there is an element named `cluster` that contains cluster numbers.

```
str(m7)
m7@cluster
```